# Random Forest: mismatch between %IncMSE and %NodePurity

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I have performed a random forest analysis of 100,000 classification trees on a rather small dataset (i.e. 28 obs. of 11 variables).

I then made a plot of the variable importance

In the resulting plots there is a substantial mismatch between %IncMSE and IncNodePurity for at least one of the important variables. The variable in fact which appears to be seventh for importance in the former (i.e. %IncMSE<0) but third in the latter.

How should I interpret this mismatch?

The variable in question is significantly correlated to one other variable that appears consistently in second place in both graphs. Could this be a clue?

Answer (score 1):

The first graph shows that if a variable is assigned values by random permutation by how much will the MSE increase. Higher the value, higher the variable importance.

On the other hand, Node purity is measured by Gini Index which is the the difference between RSS before and after the split on that variable.

Since the concept of criteria of variable importance is different in two cases, you have different rankings for different variables.

There is no fixed criterion to select the "best" measure of variable importance it depends on the problem you have at hand.